# Casting datacontext to specific type doesn't work and just skips line

Tags: c#, casting, windows-phone-8.1, datacontext

In my Windows Phone 8.1 C# application I have a databound ListView in which each item has a button the user can click (defined through the DataTemplate).

On the Click event (wired in xaml) I write the following code:

```
            FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;
            if (element.DataContext is SmappeeAPITD.actuator)
            { 
                actuator act = (SmappeeAPITD.actuator)(element.DataContext); 
                //Do what I want to do :/
            }
```

The program goes inside the if-clause, thus proving that indeed the DataContext is of the correct type (a manual breakpoint also proved this), **but once it should cast the program simply goes to  the end of the clickhandler method.**

Putting a try/catch around it doens't catch a thing, and listening to the App_UnhandledException event in the App itself also results in nothing.

I'm doing something silly wrong, but I just can't find it :/

Comment: Is there any actual code in place of that comment? Are you actually doing something with the act variable?

Comment: Oh my.... yasen, you solved it :/ Please ignore the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any code happening after the casting, it fairly obvious the code simply skips to the end of the current method.
So all is well in the world and no questions were asked :p

Thanks to use yasen for helping me find my fault